# MySQL JOIN missing proper indexes, table scanning

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have this simple JOIN:

```
SELECT my_table1.*,  
       TIME_FORMAT(time1, '%H:%i') AS time1,
       TIME_FORMAT(time2, '%H:%i') AS time2,
       TIME_FORMAT(time3, '%H:%i') AS time3,
       my_table2.*, 
       TIME_FORMAT(time2_saved, '%H:%i') AS time2_saved,
       TIME_FORMAT(time3_saved, '%H:%i') AS time3_saved,
       my_table3.device_id, my_table3.device_token,
       my_table3.device_language, my_table3.app_edition 
  FROM my_table1, my_table2, my_table3
 WHERE my_table1.flight_id = mytable_2.flight_id 
   AND my_table2.device_id = my_table3.device_id AND my_table3.app_edition = '1'
```

This seems inefficient as MySQL reports.
The indexes apparently are not optimal on this query. All tables do have indexes however, but I'm missing something.

If I run EXPLAIN before the query, MySQL returns the following:

```
1
SIMPLE
my_table2
ALL
flight_id,device_id
NULL
NULL
NULL
356

1
SIMPLE
my_table3
eq_ref
device_id
device_id
128
my_databasename.my_table2.device_id
1
Using where

1
SIMPLE
my_table1
ref
flight_id
flight_id
99
my_databasename.my_table2.flight_id
1
Using where
```

(If you prefer to see a clean table, check the actual screenshot here: http://oi48.tinypic.com/20kov3d.jpg)

As you can see the first row displays a "ALL" type which means it uses a full table scan. Wat am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should learn proper `join` syntax and not use the antiquated `,` in the `from` clause.

I think the problem is `table3`.  The indexing is not optimal for the query.  The better index is `table3(app_edition , device_id)`.  You might re-try the query with this.

The query should be written as:

```
SELECT my_table1.*,  
       TIME_FORMAT(time1, '%H:%i') AS time1,
       TIME_FORMAT(time2, '%H:%i') AS time2,
       TIME_FORMAT(time3, '%H:%i') AS time3,
       my_table2.*, 
       TIME_FORMAT(time2_saved, '%H:%i') AS time2_saved,
       TIME_FORMAT(time3_saved, '%H:%i') AS time3_saved,
       my_table3.device_id, my_table3.device_token,
       my_table3.device_language, my_table3.app_edition 
  FROM my_table1 join
       my_table2
       on my_table1.flight_id = mytable_2.flight_id join
       my_table3
       on my_table2.device_id = my_table3.device_id AND my_table3.app_edition = '1'
```

However, this probably does not affect the optimization strategy.

Comment: Can you help me a bit what a proper JOIN syntax would be in this case? Already had a slight idea this syntax was outdated.

Comment: Thanks so much, the EXPLAIN now returns ref type on that row. Thanks again!! Strange that I added indexes everywhere but forgot that table..

Comment: Hoorayed too soon. I have almost exact the same query where it doesn't solve the problem: only the last AND is different.. very strange